# Exporting PDF to Drive Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create export to PDF to my drive. This script currently does it. However I only want a specific range of cells to export out and I would like the name of the saving file to pull the information from a Cell in the sheet. Please help!  I have the following script:

```
function getpdf2(){
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   
      var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
      + '1C-ONDP4pZeUrlMYekvg0i8oNceASL1s4_o8oBpQuzHk'  
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=LETTER'
      + '&portrait=false'
      + '&fitw=false'       
      + '&top_margin=0.50'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.50'          
      + '&left_margin=0.50'             
      + '&right_margin=0.50'           
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'      
      + '&gid='
      + '1101884643';       

      var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      
      var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
      var fileid = DriveApp.createFile(docurl.getBlob()).setName('CAITLYN!B7.pdf').getId();
      
      var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName('CAITLYN!B7.pdf');
      var pdf = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('testss.pdf'); 
      var filetodel = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);

      if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("PDF Quotes").hasNext()){
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("PDF Quotes").next();
      filetodel.makeCopy(folder);
       }
      DriveApp.removeFile(filetodel);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no native way to export specific range, we need to access the data inside the spreadsheet.

What we need to do to simplify the exporting process is we copy the data range into a temporary sheet, and then paste it to the first set of cells.

After that, we need to hide the cells outside the copied cells.

Lastly, we export that temporary sheet into a pdf in our drive.

Here is the whole working code.

```
function exportRangeToPdf() {
  // Get the sheet id, sheet name, range of cells you want to export 
  // and the folder ID in your drive where you want to store the pdf
  var sheetId = '1ZzkBAR1EgismFCd-hxOUyC_uZKYucu7Av-lDHhrEMx4';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var sheetSrcRange = 'B5:C6';
  var driveId = '0B55C21aJsSBlfk9FTjRqOG8tb3hjR1N4MTU1YjVPNU4weGVhSldfU3F4OXladVVNMF9Ccms';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheetSrcRange);
  var sheetDstRange = 'A1:' + sheet.getRange(range.getHeight(), range.getWidth()).getA1Notation();
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveId);

  // Feel free to modify if needed
  // From sheet name (e.g. Sheet1.pdf)
  var pdfName = sheetName + '.pdf';
  // From specific cell, can be inside or outside your selected range to export (e.g. exportedPDF.pdf)
  // var pdfName = sheet.getRange('C7').getValue() + '.pdf';
  // From the combination of sheet name and range you chose (e.g. Sheet1_B5:C6.pdf)
  // var pdfName = sheetName + '_' + sheetSrcRange + '.pdf';
  
  // Create a blank spreadsheet to be able to export just the range
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('PDF');
  
  // If our range is 2 rows and 2 columns we want it to be copied from A1 to B2
  // Then we can hide the rest of columns and rows and export 
  var sheet2 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp');
  if(!sheet2){
    destSpreadsheet.insertSheet('temp').getRange(sheetDstRange).setValues(rangeValues);
    var sheet2 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp');
  }
  
  // Hide all the rows and columns that do not have content 
  sheet2.hideRows(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, sheet2.getMaxRows() - sheet2.getLastRow());
  sheet2.hideColumns(sheet2.getLastColumn() + 1, sheet2.getMaxColumns() - sheet2.getLastColumn());
  // Delete the first sheet that is automatically created when you create a new spreadsheet
  destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
  
  // Export our new spreadsheet to PDF
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  folder.createFile(theBlob);
  
  // Delete the spreadsheet we created to export this range. 
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Sample Data:

[image: sample data]

Output:

[image: sample output][image: sample output2]

Comment: Do you know what code I need to use for the pdfName to make it be the information in specific cell?

Comment: can you give an example of the output you want to have? `pdfName`. Do you mean, if sheet name is `Sheet1` and range is let's say `B5:D10`, `pdfName` would be `Sheet1_B5:D10.pdf`? If so then yes. If you mean the `pdfName` is getting the name from a specific cell, it would also be possible.

Comment: @Caitlyn, i have updated the answer above to show the possible variations of exported pdf name.

Comment: @Caitlyn, was I able to answer your question? If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank you. Yes it did

Comment: If it does, kindly accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same challenge in a different way that eliminates code and works effectively for me. Instead of writing a script to create a tab, copy data, delete what I don't want, etc. I just create an "Export" tab and use query to pull in the data I want to export on a regular basis.

In my case, I want to export columns in a different order, so I use arrayformula to pull in individual columns from the Primary Data Tab into an array and then run a query against it. Notice I also filter data ("Col7<>'Completed') in the query to pull in only the rows I want. Finally, you'll see that the filter references Col7 and not a column letter. When you use arrayformula, you must refer to the columns by their position in the array (Col1, Col2, etc.)

=query(ArrayFormula({'Primary Data Tab'!AJ:AJ,{'Primary Data Tab'!G:G}&" "&{'Primary Data Tab'!I:I},'Primary Data Tab'!M:M,'Primary Data Tab'!E:E,'Primary Data Tab'!F:F,'Primary Data Tab'!AK:AK,'Primary Data Tab'!AI:AI,'Primary Data Tab'!W:W,'Primary Data Tab'!K:K,'Primary Data Tab'!B:B,'Primary Data Tab'!C:C,'Primary Data Tab'!Y:Y}),"select * where Col7<>'Completed' and Col7<>'Cancelled'",1)

You can simplify this by just bringing in the entire sheet and using a query to select columns and filter it:
=query('Primary Data Tab'!A:AJ,"select A,B,D,G,T,AD where G<>'Completed' and G<>'Cancelled'",1)

Once you've done this, the data in the tab automatically reflects the Primary Data Tab and you can just export it at any time.